# Shift, concat and divide over 90 times on a 250MB dataframe efficiently in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

While trying to transform a simple dataset, I'm facing performance and memory consumption issues with pandas. Basically, I'm trying to shift a grouped (by index) dataset 90 times, and then divide the values of the shifted columns.

My base data frame is about 255MB in-memory (around 11M rows and 5 columns) and is loaded using parquet and has multi-index. Shifting and concatenating this much data, using methods I tried, causing either ridiculous memory consumption (I'm assuming it's because of the way pandas manages memory and copies of the data frame in the process).

Even if my machine is not limited-bound, the operation itself takes so long that I consider it impractical. I expect and assume this can be done in a matter of minutes. Am I wrong?

To be more specific, here is what I'm trying to perform:

1. For each column in the data frame, create a new column with shifted data X days back, `for X in range(1, 90)`;
2. Divide the value of each column by the previous-column-shift. (so `columnA.shift(90)` is divided by `columnA.shift(89)`;
3. Concatenating everything into one data frame.

I find it a bit difficult to explain it purely in words, so here is an example of the data manipulation:

This is the original dataset (only 2 columns for the example):

[image]

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(
    [[20, 43],
    [40, 52],
    [30, 34],
    [60, 52],
    [44, 66],
    [55, 72],
    [34, 34],
    [51, 17]],
    columns=['a', 'b'])
```

After the shifts:

[image]

After the division of the values:

[image]

Below are some code snippets I tried.

Concatenating all shifted columns in the loop (this without the `divide` operation). This is actually wrong, as I forgot to perform `groupby()` here:

```py
for w in range(1, 91):
    data = pd.concat([
        data,
        (data[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']].shift(w).rename(
            columns={
                'c1': f'c1_{w}',
                'c2': f'c2_{w}',
                'c3': f'c3_{w}',
                'c4': f'c4_{w}',
                'c5': f'c5_{w}'
            }
        ))], axis=1)
```

Using `groupby().apply()`:

```py
def _myfunc(x):
    for w in range (1, 4):
        return (x.shift(w) / x.shift(w - 1)).rename({
            'c1': f'c1_{w}',
            'c2': f'c2_{w}',
            'c3': f'c3_{w}',
            'c4': f'c4_{w}',
            'c5': f'c5_{w}'
            })
        
data.groupby("mylevel")[['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']].apply(_myfunc)
```

Will be glad for assistance here.

Comment: Am I missing something if we shift and divide once, the rest of the 89 columns are just that result shifted more? If so I wonder why we need that materialised in memory; it's all the same data with an offset, so why keep 90 copies of it in memory?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling the device is between each column and the previous one. So shift(90) is divided by shirt(89) and so forth.

Comment: but no matter how many times you shift, the division results will always be identical, just shifted down `N` rows. that's also what your [expected output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPCYW.png) shows.

Comment: @CrispyHoliday: could you please provide info on @tdy's comment? Specifically, all shifted sub-matrices are the same result, shifted: `(df.shift(n+1) / df.shift(n)).equals((df.shift(1) / df).shift(n))`.

Comment: Additionally: your expected result is going to be 255MB * 90, i.e. 22GB, right?

Comment: You also mention `groupby()`. Group by what? The example data doesn't show any "mylevel" in the index, nor any repeat in the index. This may change the problem quite a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows what I was asking in the comment:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size=(100, 1)), columns=('a',))
shift_1 = df['a'].shift(1) / df['a']
assert all((df['a'].shift(90) / df['a'].shift(89)).dropna() == shift_1.shift(89).dropna())
```

The dropna() is just there because `np.nan != np.nan`

So, why keep all the copies, when you could do the shift before lookup?

Comment: although this technically doesn't answer the question as written, i'm upvoting because this seems like the practical solution. i suspect there's an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) going on here.

Comment: @tdy My thought exactly. Sometime the answer is asking a different question.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer based on your provided data:

Based on what you provided, I was able to create this without needing to concatenate dataframes; runs fast with the small set from your question.

Import pandas and create dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    [[20, 43],
    [40, 52],
    [30, 34],
    [60, 52],
    [44, 66],
    [55, 72],
    [34, 34],
    [51, 17]],
    columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Get a list of existing columns prior to shifting (easier to iterate over):

```py
cols = list(data.columns)
```

Iterate over column names from dataframe and requested range:

```py
#iterate over desired columns
for ab in cols:
    #range 1 to 90
    for i in range(1,91):
        #construct new column name
        col_name = ab+'_shift'+str(i)
        #add new column to dataframe
        data[col_name] = data[ab].shift(i) / data[ab].shift(i-1)
```

Output for new columns (I omitted the b_shifts from the picture because there are so many columns):
[image: column output]

**Note**: this solution does not retain the original shifted column values, it seemed to me that you just wanted the divided values. Not too hard to add those into the dataframe during the `for` loop if you need them though.

### Answer using 5 col 5 mil row dataframe

I was curious on how this solution would perform for a dataframe that more closely resembled your stated input of 5 columns and 11 million rows, so I decided to try it out.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(5000000, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE')) 

cols = list(df.columns)

for ab in cols:
    for i in range(1,91):
        col_name = ab+'_shift'+str(i)
        df[col_name] = df[ab].shift(i) / df[ab].shift(i-1)
```

`df.info()` indicates the initial dataframe sat here: `memory usage: 190.7 MB`-- fairly close to your 250MB.

My first run crashed Jupyter, so I refined it and just ran it for one column.
Using `time`, it took 5.28 seconds to add the 90 columns for just `A` and my new `df.info()` reads  `memory usage: 3.5 GB`- modified code for reference:

```py
from time import time

start = time()
for ab in cols[:1]:
    for i in range(1,91):
        col_name = ab+'_shift'+str(i)
        df[col_name] = df[ab].shift(i) / df[ab].shift(i-1)
print(time()-start)
```

That's a pretty substantial jump!

Running it for `A`, `B`, and `C` (three columns): 22.43 seconds and `memory usage: 10.2 GB`

Running it for `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` (four columns): Crashed again

I monitored my system's memory usage throughout the process (just from System Monitor) and after the third column, it spiked up in memory and hit the full system RAM available- causing Jupyter to crash.

I'm sure there's a way you could code around this memory hogging by either doing it in chunks, writing part to disk, or possibly encouraging Jupyter to page. FYI I'm running Ubuntu on a 16-core AMD CPU with 32GB DDR4, so you'll probably run into a similar issue unless you're rocking 64GB+ memory.

#### Writing to csvs and re-importing

To get around the memory exploding, I tried to just do a simple write to disk and reread upon completion:

```py
from time import time

start = time()
for ab in cols:
    df_shift = pd.DataFrame() #this df gets wiped out on each run, but we have it on disk
    for i in range(1,91):
        col_name = ab+'_shift'+str(i)
        df_shift[col_name] = df[ab].shift(i) / df[ab].shift(i-1)
    df_shift.to_csv(ab+'_shifted.csv', index=False)
    
print(time()-start)
```

This takes A LOT longer because it has to write to the SSD. Total time to write **just** `A_shifted.csv` to disk was 314.77 seconds

I didn't try to read them from disk to concatenate them, but if this is the route you go, you could try something like this:

```py
#concat all csvs
df_shift_all = pd.DataFrame()
for ab in cols:
    df_shift = pd.read_csv(ab+'_shifted.csv')
    df_shift_all = pd.concat([df_shift_all,df_shift])
```

Again, I didn't run this very last code block, so I can't guarantee the syntax will 100% work. The rest I did run and tried out!